# How to find element value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all class call **Position** $(".Position") and get then find the value that == 4 and then show the id.

```
<input type="Text" id="#34" value="1" class="Position">
<input type="Text" id="#22" value="2" class="Position">
<input type="Text" id="#37" value="3" class="Position">
<input type="Text" id="#41" value="4" class="Position">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
alert($("input.Position[value='4']").attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you  have to take off the '#' from your id's.

```
<input type="Text" id="34" value="1" class="Position">
```

Then you can find the input you are looking for with the following selector:

```
$('input.Position[value=4]').attr('id')
```

Comment: You should put the tag name before any class declarations in the selector - speeds it up.  Probably insignificant in this case, but a good practice to get into. `$('input.Position[value=4]').attr('id')`